# GitHub API returning message requires authentication while I try to login

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, github-api

```
const fetchUser =  async () =>{
    let username : any = (document.getElementById('username') as HTMLInputElement).value;
    let password : any = (document.getElementById('password') as HTMLInputElement).value; 
    const profile = await fetch("https://api.github.com/user", {
        headers:{
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + window.btoa(username + ":" + password)
        }
    })
   const profileResponse = await profile.json()
    console.log(profileResponse)
}
const handleSubmit =(e:any) =>{
    e.preventDefault()
    fetchUser()
}
```

I tried to log in with GitHub credentials using GitHub API but it returns the required authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github.com has discontinued password authentication to the API using `username` and `password`.

[Reference](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/other-authentication-methods#via-username-and-password)

Comment: But that is not supposed to be

Comment: What do you mean and why?

Comment: is there any way to log in with a username and password using GitHub API?

Comment: I think **No** because it is clearly stated that form `November 13, 2020` the service is discontinued for all available plans including Github Pro and Enterprise cloud.

Comment: are you sure brother? Actually, I have an assignment where I have to implement a GitHub login system. If you don't mind could share the info link, please?

Comment: Its just the way you are authenticating a user to your app. You can use OAuth in your app to login using Github. [Here](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps) is everything.

Comment: But I want to make an app where random people can access their account by providing their credentials. Is it possible by using OAuth?

Comment: With OAuth you can provide the user an option to `Login with Github` to your app and the github will provide you with a `access token` which you can use for fetching users data.  Just like Instagram and Facebook(you can login with facebook even without username and password).

Comment: Could you suggest to me some tutorials where I can explore the GitHub OAuth concept?

Comment: Sorry I don't have any idea. You can start here. [Github Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps).